# How to return different types according to constexpr parameter in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Example code:

```
class A {
// ......
}

class B {
// ......
}


// type of var1 is A
constexpr auto var1 = function_or_macro("A");


// type of var2 is B
constexpr auto var2 = function_or_macro("B");

// compile error
// constexpr auto var3 = function_or_macro("Other");
```

Can I write a template function or macro `function_or_macro()` to achive this goal in C++11?

The input parameter is always constexpr, I think the compiler can determain the return value type at compile time in this case. But I can't found a way to write the correct code.

Note: Can not use `function_or_macro<A>("A")`.

Comment: Return an [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)? Otherwise you need to use a template for the return type (possibly with specialization) instead of passing a normal argument.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `std::variant` only available after C++17, how to do this in C++11?

Comment: [Boost variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/variant.html) (if you're already using Boost)? Or as mentioned go with templates.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments aren't constant expressions. You can use a function template though:

```
class A {
// ......
};

class B {
// ......
};

template <char C>
auto function();

template <>
auto function<'A'>() { return A{}; }

template <>
auto function<'B'>() { return B{}; }

int main() {
    A a = function<'A'>();
    B b = function<'B'>();
}
```

However, it depends on the calling code, whether this has any benefit  compared to simply using two functions `A functionA();` and `B functionB();`.

In C++11 and earlier the above will not work, then you can resort to using a trait for the return type:

```
class A {
// ......
};

class B {
// ......
};

template <char C>
struct return_type;

template <>
struct return_type<'A'> { using type = A; };

template <>
struct return_type<'B'> { using type = B; };

template <char C>
typename return_type<C>::type function() { return {}; }

int main() {
    A a = function<'A'>();
    B b = function<'B'>();
}
```

Comment: Deduced return type only available after C++14, so `auto function();` will raise compile error in C++11. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @MingfeiGao sorry didnt see that you are using C++11. I added a version that is fine with C++11